# Reading and writing on Instance store disk of Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does it cost any money to read or write on your instance store disk?  Tell me your reasons.

Answer (score 0):

No.  There are no IO  request charges for instance store disk (aka ephemeral disk) from an EC2 instance.

However, EBS volumes do incur IO request charges, or pIOPS charges for Provisioned IOPS EBS volumes.

You can read more about EBS volume charges here: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#EBS